# Can $scope.$watch determine equivalency of two objects?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've built a directive that gets its data by `$parse`'ing from an Angular expression in one of my `$attrs`. The expression is typically a simple filter applied to a list model, the evaluation of which will change when the parent `$scope` is modified.

To monitor when it should update the data it's using, my directive is using a `$scope.$watch` call, with a custom function that re-$`parse`'s the expression. The problem I'm running into is that `$parse` will generate a new object instance from the expression, so `$watch` sees the value as changed even when the data in each object is completely equivalent. This results in my code hitting the `$digest` iteration cap very quickly due to actions taken in the `$watch` callback.

To get around this I am doing the following, currently:

```
 var getter = $parse($attrs.myExpression);
 $scope.$watch(function () {
    var newVal = getter($scope);
    if (JSON.stringify($scope.currentData) !== JSON.stringify(newVal)) {
      return newVal;
    } else {
      return $scope.currentData;
    }
  }, function (newVal) {
    $scope.currentData = newVal;
    // other stuff
  });
```

However, I don't like relying on `JSON` as an intermediary here, nor using my `$watch`'ed function itself to evaluate equivalency of old and new values. Is there a flag the `$watch` can take to determine if two objects are equivalent, or is there a better approach for handling this kind of situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi you should use this,

```
scope.$watch('data', function (newVal) { /*...*/ }, true);
```

This has been answerd here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712089/how-to-deep-watch-an-array-in-angularjs)

Comment: Just what I was looking for -- the optional deep compare argument. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, had the same question the first time I came across this. Just don't forget to mark has the answer to help others. Thanks