# How to have an Observable in Coffee Script and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I am using Angular.js and CoffeeScript. I have a variable in the controller called Current Page. The Current Page is bound to a text box. How do I trigger a method call in the controller when a user changes the value of Current Page.i.e Let's say the value of the current page is 5. When the user changes it, I want to a call a method in the controller in Angular. How do I do this ??

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `$scope.$watch.` in your controller.

```
  $scope.currentPage = 1;

   $scope.$watch('currentPage', function() {
       alert('hey, currentPage has changed!');
   }, true);
```

Check out [Using scope.$watch and scope.$apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply) and [$watch an object in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19455564/697079)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This gave me the correct direction to work at.

Answer (score 0):

I used ng-blur and called a method in my controller. using $scope.$watch it fires even as the user is entering. Hence used ng-blur.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="controller.currentPage" ng-blur="controller.handlePageChange()" class="form-  control"/><span>Of</span>
```

In the controller I have this:

```
  handlePageChange:=>
    if (this.currentPage != this.data.currentPage) && (this.currentPage >= 1 && this.currentPage <= this.data.maxPages())
      console.log 'The page has indeed changed'
      this.data.paginate(this.currentPage)
```