# Angularjs watch service object

Tags: angularjs, service, watch

Why can't I watch a object in a service.
Ive got a simple variable working, but a object wont work.
http://plnkr.co/edit/S4b2g3baS7dwQt3t8XEK?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.service('test', ['$http', '$rootScope',
            function ($http,   $rootScope) {

  var data = 0;
  var obj  = {
                "data": 0
              };

  this.add = function(){
    obj.data += 1;
    console.log('data:', obj);
  };

  this.getData     = function() { return obj; };

}]);

app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$filter', 'test',
                          function($scope,   $rootScope,   $filter,   test) {

  //test controller
  $scope.add = function(){
    test.add();
  };
  $scope.test = test;
  $scope.$watch('test.getData()', function(newVal){
    console.log('data changes into: ', newVal)
  });
}]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [$watch an object in angular](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455501/watch-an-object-in-angular)

Comment: I suggest you to write `function(){
           return test.getData();
       },` instead 'test.getData()'. By this way you can avoid bugs, because angular doesn't validate string definition.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to pass true as the last parameter of the $watch function so that the equality check is angular.equals. Otherwise only reference equality is checked.

```
$scope.$watch('test.getData()', function(newVal){
  console.log('data changes into: ', newVal)
}, true);
```

Duplicate question:
[$watch an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455501/watch-an-object-in-angular)

**EDIT**

As mentioned bellow, the code includes a bad practice – having a service referenced in `$scope`. It is not necessary to reference it in scope, since `$watch` also accepts a getter function as first argument. Clean solution uses this function to return the watched array as is in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26801155/1956072).
 `$scope.$watch(function() { return test.getData(); } ...`

To list a complete solution you could also use `$watchCollection` instead to solve the reference equality check problem.

Answer (score 20):

injecting whole services into a scope is not something I would do.

I would prefer to watch a function returning the value :

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return test.getData(); }, function(newVal) { 
    /* Do the stuff */
}, true);
```

Comment: Actually this is the only way I was able to get the watch to work when watching an array instead of a function (e.g. test.data).