# Angular watch doesn't work with controllerAs syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch, angularjs-controlleras

Have a problem with watching response.

I have a SettingsCtrl as settings and this is my view:

```html
<input  type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="settings.test.one"  />
<input  type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="settings.test.second"  />
```

And this is my Controller:

```js
app.controller('SettingsCtrl', function ($scope, settingsFactory, Test) {
  
  var vm = this;
  
  
  settingsFactory.test().then(function(response){
  
     vm.test = response;
  })
  
  /////  OR
  
  vm.test = Test; // this is from ui-router resolve
  
  
    $scope.$watch(angular.bind('vm', function () {
    return vm.test;
    }), function (newV, oldV) {
    console.log(newV, oldV); 
    });
  
    $scope.$watch(function watch(scope){
     return vm.test;
    }), function handle(newV, oldV) {
    console.log(newV, oldV);
    });
  
    $scope.$watch('vm', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        console.log('newVal, oldVal', newVal, oldVal);
    });
  
  });
```

I've been searching and have found different solutions, but non of them works.

**** It's watch only first time, when controller is loaded and I see my  console logs, but when I try to make changes watchers do nothing.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, your $watch is hit the first time a controller is loaded, but not when you change something in the object. If that's true, then try this:

```
$scope.$watch('vm', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log('newVal, oldVal', newVal, oldVal);
}, true);
```

By default, $watch function watches the reference so if you only change a property of the watched object it will not be fired. By adding `true` at the end, you start deep watching, and you will get a hit each time you change a property of the object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot about deep watching. It's helped.

Answer (score 2):

AngularJS still works as expected:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('SettingsCtrl', function($scope) {

    var vm = this

    vm.test = ''


    $scope.$watch(function watch(scope) {
        return vm.test;
      },
      function handle(newV, oldV) {
        if (newV && newV.name && newV.name !== oldV.name) {
          vm.test.watchedName = newV.name.toUpperCase()
        }
      }, true);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='SettingsCtrl as settings'>
    <input type='text' ng-model='settings.test.name' />
    <pre><code>
 {{ settings.test.watchedName }}
 </code></pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code for watch.

```
 $scope.$watch(function(){
    return ctrl.test;
},function(newVal,oldVal){
    console.log(newVal,oldVal);
},true)
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GD7j/10/)

You will need deep watch on object.

This link [$watch an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455501/watch-an-object) will help you to understand this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but another answerer was first, that's why I marked this answer, sorry, but anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try calling the vm variable as controller.vmVariable in watcher. Controller is your controller name and then your variable assigned in vm.

```
$scope.$watch('controller.vmVariable', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    console.log('newVal, oldVal', newVal, oldVal);
});
```

Comment: Like this: $scope.$watch('SettingsCtrl.test', ... ) ?   Nothing :(

Comment: In routing your are specified some name for controller right? in 'controllerAs' field. Could you please try with that ?

Comment: I've already try this: SettingsCtrl as settings -  $scope.$watch('settings.wm', ... ) Nothing

Comment: But! All of solutions start only one first time when controller starts. But no reaction on changes. Maybe there is another problem?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me after referring to a github post (https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/issues/428) and (http://jsbin.com/levewagufo/edit?html,js,console,output) was to rename the controller from vm = this to (in your case ) settings = this in the beginning of writing the controller. This makes sure the references match up to the "controller as" declaration from the view. Hope this helps

In View:

```
ng-controller="AddDetailController as addDetailsCtrl"
```

In Controller Js file:

```
 $scope.$watch('addDetailsCtrl.currentPage', function (current, original) {
        console.log(current + ":" + original);    });
```