# does angularjs $watch every property on a $scope or only those referenced in template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Since all watches are evaluated on every $digest, keeping their number low is a good perf practice. To rephrase the question title, is there a perf penalty for declaring either a variable or method on $scope inside a controller, when those aren't being referenced by related template (if there is a penalty one could declare those as local variable on controller object instead).

Comment: Yes there is. Angular triggers a $digest cycle every time anything in the scope changes (dirty/clean check). So it has to loop over every variable in your scope and check if it changed.

Comment: Note that AngularJS doesn't do a $digest anytime something changes, it'll $digest anytime the scope is $apply'd.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv That's wrong. **First**, A digest happens only when it's being triggered ( mostly by directives / services ). **Second**, only registered watchers are being checked not the whole scope object.

Comment: OK, sorry about the misunderstanding. It triggers a $digest cycle every time anything in the scope is applied. It does however loop over the whole scope and checks if anything changed.

Comment: Again, it loops over the **$$watchers** list not over the entire scope. I never heard the angular guys say you should avoid keeping unnecessary data on the scope they only warn about $watchers.

Comment: Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KQ4uy/1/) that might clear up some of the confusion.  It shows every time a $digest is run and it changes two scope variables- one, every quarter second, done outside angular (using `setInterval`) and one, every 2 seconds, "inside Angular" using Angular's $interval- so it's done within an apply.  Only the Angular aware undate triggers a $digest, but both bindings are then updated once the digest occurs.

Comment: After actually reading the code I can say I was terribly wrong. Angular does not dirty check everything on the scope. It cares about the watchers only.

Answer (score 0):

When you place something on `$scope`, it can be watched. You can `$watch` anything on the scope perfecly fine, even if it is not on a template.

Is there a performance penalty? AngularJS usually compares references when you watch objects, and only compares the [watched objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208560/does-angularjs-watch-every-property-on-a-scope-or-only-those-referenced-in-tem/21208666#comment31939151_21208560), not everything on the scope. So unless you are doing a [deep compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712089/how-to-deep-watch-an-array-in-angularjs) on a very large object or array that you are watching, it should't take noticeable time.

For testing performance and seeing if your changes are slowing anything down, you can use the [AngularJS Batarang](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/).

Comment: Just to add to this, you can watch things not on the scope by returning it from a function passed as the first argument to $watch.