# $watch is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Watch is not being called on change in the item. It works on load, and loads the map correctly. However when I change `event_type` with a drop down, and it never makes it inside the function. I checked with `concole.log`.

Actual `event_type` does change, it displays new value on the screen with `{{ event_type.type }}`

```
$scope.event_type = { id: 0, type:'All' }
$scope.$watch( 'event_type', function(val) {
    $scope.markers = Events.venues(val.type)
    }, true)
```

Comment: I don't think you want the single quotes around it. You might want to also put the watch on event_type.type and not event_type.

Comment: it has to be single quotes for the expression, adding .type made it not work at all

Comment: I saw that when testing. The answer I posted should help you.

Comment: it makes sense, and should work but still nothing, I am updating the question with new code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's called deep diving or deep watching. Regardless, it's a 3rd parameter on the $watch you want to set to true.

You also can pass in the new value as a parameter instead of reading from event_type. As seen below.

```
$scope.$watch( 'event_type', function(newVal) {
    $scope.markers = Events.venues(newVal.type)
}, true);
```

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/YMmVPKDMeUcK5Pvz2Z0z?p=preview

Let me know if something here doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's called deep watching. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712089/how-to-deep-watch-an-array-in-angularjs

Comment: still nothing, never enters the function second time

Comment: Did you pass true to the watch? That's the important part here. $scope.$watch('event_type', function() {..}, true);

Comment: Nevermind, I see from your new code that you did. It seems like the $watch is actually working properly and it may be a binding issue or something else. Are you able to make a plnkr that shows more of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: would be fairly complicated, it uses a dropdown to get the value with ng-model and pass it to google map markers.

Comment: Gotcha. "Actual event_type does change, it displays new value on the screen with {{ event_type.type }}" hints that the $watch does work. You could add a console.log('Value has changed'); to verify, but I don't think it's an issue with the watch at this point.

Comment: It logs first time on load, but when it changes .. it doesnt change. So watch never is run again