# How do I detect a change in a multi-dimension array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, watch

If I have the following data structure:

```
Model: { 
    Estimates: [{ 
        Id: 1, DataItems: [{Id: 1, Amount: 100}, {Id: 2, Amount: 200}] },
        Id: 2, DataItems: [{Id: 3, Amount: 300}, {Id: 4, Amount: 400}] }
    ]}
```

How can I set up an Angular $watch to detect when any of the Amount values change?

I tried using

```
$scope.$watch("budget.Estimates.DataItems", function () {
    console.log("Watch Fired");
});
```

with no luck.

Also, is there a nice, Angular way to aggregate the sum of all these Amount values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712089/how-to-deep-watch-an-array-in-angularjs - might help.

Comment: `budget.Estimates` is array, so it has no property `DataItems`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link, tymeJV.  That pointed me in the right direction.

The solution was to do this:

```
$scope.$watch("budget.Estimates", function () {
    console.log("Watch Fired");
}, true);
```

The 3rd parameter signals angular to deep compare the values.  Not especially efficient, but it works...