# Attach $watch to variable inside list of dict

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to attach watch on `order`. I am not sure how to add watch to variable inside list of dict.
Inside controller,

```
cart_list = [{'order':'single'},{'order':'single'},{'order':'twice'}];

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cart_list.length; i++) {
    $scope.$watch('cart_list[i].order', function() {
        console.log("Inside watch");
        if($scope.cart_list[i].order=='single'){
            console.log("with single order");
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'order' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way i can think of making this watch work is by using function expression in the watch. The code becomes like

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cart_list.length; i++) {
    setupWatch($scope.cart_list[i]);
}

function setupWatch(item) {
   $scope.$watch(function () {
            return item
        }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log("Inside watch");
            if (newValue.order == 'single') {
                console.log("with single order");
            }
        }, true);
}
```

I have not tried it, but i think this should work.

Also i am added strict object equality as the last parameter.

Comment: Watch out, the `i` will always take the last value, the common pitfall in Javascript of defining functions within loops!

Comment: Ya! a closure needs to be setup.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to watch the entire collection rather than watching each object separately.

I hope this may help:

```
 $scope.$watchCollection("cart_list", function(newV, oldV){
     if(newV and newV.length > 0)
     {
       // do your stuff
       for(var i=0; newV.length; i++)
       {
          if(newV[i].order == "single")
            console.log("with single order");
       }
     }
 }, true);
```

Comment: the problem with this approach is, it does not watch array items for change, so even if `order` value changes the watch is not fired.

Comment: It will do item watch, I am sure of it.. as we are using Equality depth watch, with "true" attribute at the end. Have you tried it?

Comment: Or possibly you can $watch on collection with true as third argument, instead of $watchCollection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712089/how-to-deep-watch-an-array-in-angularjs

Comment: I have not tried but as per documentation there is no deep equality watch, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: Thanks. `$watchCollection` is new to me. I will look into this. @Chandermani solution works for me.