# Track changes in a multi-level object in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, object

There is an object. It is dynamic and the data in it are constantly changing, say so.

```
$scope.object = {
    "className": "?????",
    "property": [
        {
            "name": "???"
        },
        {
            "prado": "???"
        }
    ]
}
```

What needs? And it is necessary for the project `$scope.object` monitor any change in, at all levels of the object. Maybe there is a method similar to the `$watchCollection`, only advanced? Or another way to keep track of?

I would be glad of any tip. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What would be the reason to watch the entire object if angularjs does the update in UI for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$watch has third optional parameter:

```
$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);
```

According to documentation:

> When objectEquality == true, inequality of the watchExpression is
>   determined according to the angular.equals function. To save the value
>   of the object for later comparison, the angular.copy function is used.
>   This therefore means that watching complex objects will have adverse
>   memory and performance implications.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

See also [How to deep watch an array in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712089/how-to-deep-watch-an-array-in-angularjs)

But use it carefully.

Comment: Thank yuo Robert! This third option has helped. And I'll be careful.