# Angularjs onchange datetime picker not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetimepicker

First I want to say that I've read many fixes, but noone have fixed my problem.

I'm using this library, https://github.com/amittkSharma/extended-datetimepicker, I need to call a function after my input gets updated.

Examples of how to use the clock can be found in this link, https://rawgit.com/amittkSharma/extended-datetimepicker/master/index.html, this is basically how I'm using the clocks, attaching them to an ng-model.

This library uses a directive, and opens a clock to pick time or date, I'm using it for the time part, I liked this clock very much, so I'm using it. But I cannot find a way to catch the onchange event for my input.

In the directive code there is this comment in line 134, *//@TODO custom event to trigger input*, which I thought I might add something there, I tried to add an element.on('change') function, but I didn't get it to work, so I'm out of ideas.

I'm using this library to load a bunch a times and make picking time easier. So I need a solution that works like inside on a ng-repeat, or something I can iterate.

Any help would be very much appreciatted.

**EDIT**

After the answer given by samura, I did some more investigation as to why it wasn't working on my $scope variable.

I didn't mention this, but my $scope variable is an array, and this was the problem (**this is why you need to be as detailed as possible when your are asking a question**). You need to add a 3rd parameter to watch for changes inside the array, you need to add true.

Like this:

```
$scope.$watch('timesArray', function() {
    alert('hey, time has changed!');
}, true); //here the 3rd param
```

Taken from: [How to deep watch an array in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712089/how-to-deep-watch-an-array-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this input

```
<input mdc-datetime-picker date="false" time="true" type="text" id="time" short-time="true"
           placeholder="Time"
           min-date="minDate"
           format="hh:mm a"
           ng-model="time">
```

You can use

```
$scope.$watch('time', function() {
    alert('hey, time has changed!');
});
```

inside your `controller` to catch any change on the `time` property.

Comment: I already tried that, and it did not work.

Comment: Ok, your code works perfectly, let me make some edits to my question. Maybe yoy can help a bit more.